# Spring: Can I define labels for model attributes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am building validation in Spring framework and would like to display custom (localized) error messages. For example: *Field 'Repeat password' cannot be empty.*

How can I define field label and pass it as argument to error message?

This is my form object with some validation constraints

```
public class RegisterForm
{
    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    private String email;
    @NotEmpty
    @Length( min=6, message = "{register.error.password.length.min}")
    private String password;
    @NotEmpty
    private String repeatPassword;
}
```

and my custom message for *NotEmpty* constraint is like this:

```
NotEmpty=Field {0} cannot be empty
```

{0} in message is replaced by field name (*repeatPassword*). How can I pass field label (*Repeat password* or *Passwort wiederholen*) to this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can pass the field label to the message manually. However, you can specify the label in the message properties which would be resolved based on the field name.

So in the message properties you would have the custom parameterized text for `NotEmpty` plus the labels for each of the field names.

```
# Parameterized custom message
NotEmpty=Field {0} cannot be empty 

# Field labels
email=Email
password=Password
repeatPassword=Repeat password
```

The full message would then be resolved to `Field Repeat password cannot be empty` etc.

For the different label translations you'd just specify those in the locale specific properties files.

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know it is so easy. Additional info: if there are multiple form objects with same attribute name, but you would like different label for each attribute, simply write it like this `userForm.name=User name`, `companyForm.name=Company name`. companyForm or userForm are names of form object injected into theme.